# Print node teaser from nid

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I print a teaser from a specific nid? It's driving me crazy.

I tried this:

```
$teaser = TRUE;
$page = FALSE;
$nid = 20;
print node_view(node_load(array('nid' => $nid)), $teaser, $page, FALSE);
```

but the only output is 'Array'.

I also tried this:

```
$node = node_load(20);
$teaser_content = $node->body['und']['0']['summary'];
print $teaser_content;
```

But this is only giving me the **summary** of the node, not the teaser specified with `<!--break-->`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Drupal 7 there is no `$teaser` argument to the [`node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7) function, instead there is a `$view_mode` argument which takes a string (usually `teaser` or `full`, the default is `full`). The code you're currently using would work perfectly for Drupal 6 though.

This code will work for Drupal 7:

```
$view_mode = 'teaser';
$nid = 20;

$node = node_load($nid);

print render(node_view($node, $view_mode));
```

Comment: Just one thing: is there a way to print it 'clean' so you don't have all the wrapper divs etc. of node.tpl.php? I would like to add an ellipsis after the last word of the teaser but now it is printed in a new paragraph.

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, but essentially you would pass a custom `$view_mode` to `node_view()` and then check `$view_mode` in the `node.tpl.php` file to not include certain wrappers if the view mode is your custom one, e.g. `if ($view_mode != 'custom_view') {`.

Comment: Thanks, I almost got it working now. I have a custom view mode now that I could use in an if-statement. I only need to know how I get the default content of node.tpl.php in the else-statement (or maybe another structure, I don't know PHP). Something like this:
`if ($view_mode == 'clean_teaser') {
 print render($content);
}
else {
// node.tpl.php default content
} `

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/render/7) function.

```
$teaser = TRUE;
$page = FALSE;
$nid = 20;
print render(node_view(node_load(array('nid' => $nid)), $teaser, $page, FALSE));
```

Be careful using `node_view()` directly on `node_load()` as it'll whitescreen if `node_load()` fails to successfully load the node.

Comment: Have you enabled the display for the teaser?

Comment: But Drupal seems to ignore my custom teaser breaking point. When I use for example panels to display my teaser it uses the default value of 600 characters to render the content instead of my specified breaking point (I use full HTML as input format).

Comment: That problem mentioned in my last comment is solved now (see [this](http://drupal.org/node/881006#comment-5321794) topic), but your script still isn't working.

Comment: Do you have at least one field format set to anything other than <hidden> for the fields in the enabled teaser display.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 6 it's just

```
$node = node_load(20);
print node_view($node, 'teaser');
```